# Persistent error condition relating to Sqlite metadata

Tags: sqlite, delphi, dbexpress

I've run into a very puzzling problem regarding a table in a Sqlite database.
The table has this simple DDL definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [MATable2] ([ID] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  [AName] VARCHAR(20),  [AMemo] MEMO)
```

Using XE6, DBExpress and v.3.8.5.0 of sqlite3.dll I've created a project
to investigate another SO q.  The project (32-bit target) is deliberately as minimalist as I could make it, i.e. I've just pulled off the component palette a SqlConnection,
SqlQuery (which just does a 'SELECT * from [MATable2]'), DataSetProvider, CDS,
DataSource, DBGrid and DBNavigator wired up in left-to-right order as it were.
The code is equally minimalist, and I don't think I need show it because my
problem isn't with the code per se, which works fine.

The problem I've been getting is this: Every now and then, usually after I've made
some blunder that generates an exception (like calling CDS.Refresh in its ApplyUpdates event) the project (I would say "or its server" if the server in Sqlite's case weren't just
a dll) gets into an "error condition" which persists across restarting the XE6 IDE and
rebooting the machine.  It manifests itself by the SqlQuery.Open generating an exception
complaining about a mismatch between the expected and actual field types, e.g. in the
case of the ID field, the exception will report that it was expecting a WideMemo field but received a LargeInt one instead - it's as if there is something off by one in the table's metadata as received by the SqlQuery.

Thinking this condition might be DBX-specfic, and something to do with Sqlite column
types really being thinly-disguised memo fields, I created a FireDac equivalent
project and that gets the error condition, too.  Then, the condition clears,
as mysteriously as it appeared, usually after I delete the dataset components +
TFields and replace them.

So, my question is, does anyone know where can the error cause could be persisting, I mean
such that it survives IDE restarts and machine reboots?  My first thought was in the DFM, because of what I've said about how it spontaneously clears.  Next, I suspected the database itself, but it seems perfectly tickety-boo accessed, queried and recreated using two independent Sqlite utilities, Sqlite Expert and the Sqlite Manager add-in for Firefox.  The OS reports the disk as w/out errors.  I've looked for persisted info that might be the cause, in Ini files and the Registry, but found nothing obvious.